# Mildly not-safe-for-work challenge?

Tags: discussion, code-golf

Related to this thread on reddit: [*a link that was determined to be NSFW*]

Can I submit this as a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) question, or is it too inappropriate for StackExchange?

Comment: Kudos for asking on Meta first. Too many new users would just post it anyways. Welcome to the site!

Comment: To see what is and what is not considered inappropriate here, you can also read [Be Nice](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: I was relieved when I clicked on the link. The words "master race" made me think it was going to be a lot worse that it was! But no, vulgar sexual animations are not appropriate.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's definitely too inappropriate for Stack Exchange. However, you could trivially modify the animation to be something appropriate (like perhaps a [party blower](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elPCX.gif)).

Comment: If the link is to something inappropriate for this site, then since the question has been answered should the link be removed and replaced with a generic description of what it was?